# In sql, how to select from a json field

Tags: php, sql, json, eloquent

So I have this text(varchar) field in the database that has json with ids e.g{1,2}
How do I match in a where clause one of those ids.

I'm also using eloquent I couldn't find an answer in their docs.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you please add some code / details to your question? It would be a lot easier to find an answer, if you explain how the things you mention (textbox, json, sql) are related to each other. Show us some code!

Comment: You don't.  That's not how you use a relational database.

Comment: to match one of the ids in this json field I'd could always fetch the whole row then loop through each row and then filter the rows that do not match. I just was wondering if there is a way to filter them through the sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a "PHP" tag along with your question, so I guess a PHP solution could be considerable?

Either you could use a UDF for parsing JSON for MySQL like: https://github.com/ChrisCinelli/mysql_json

But a better way would be to select the JSON object and parse it in PHP with json_decode() (http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) and then convert the data to a more suitable database schema for your intentions.

It's rarely optimal to use a native SQL-statement on JSON-encoded data.

I would create a new table with proper indexing and then create a PHP function/method to decode the json data and insert into a new table.

Answer (score 0):

You could use some sort of "string contains" or regex logic, but this is error prone. Most databases offer, however, support for storing and querying json in the database, e.g. like `JSON data type` in [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html). Hope this helps.